# How to configure automatic failover of storage account when using AzureWebJobsStorage for Web Job Timer Triggers

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, webjob, azure-webjobs-continuous

I have an Azure Web Job that runs on a TimerTrigger to put some messages on a Service Bus queue. I have deployed this Web Job on 2 separate regions, for high availability in case one region goes down. As per https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/TimerTrigger, I can see that the distributed lock mechanism is working perfectly and the timer is only executing in one region at a time, so there are no duplicate requests coming through.

However, the Web Jobs in both the regions are using the same common storage account, and the storage account is deployed to just one region. I can't use 2 separate storage accounts, because then I lose on the distributed lock functionality. I know that Azure provides Geo-redundant storage for my storage account, so the data is replicated to a secondary region.

My question is - in the event of a disaster in one region (specifically the primary region of the storage account), is there a way to have the web job automatically failover to the secondary end point? Right now, I have the "AzureWebJobsStorage" application setting specified to be one of the shared access keys of the storage account.

Appreciate any pointers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on the storage SDK but I've linked two docs that may help walk you through how to make your app highly available.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-disaster-recovery-guidance?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/geo-redundant-design?tabs=legacy
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-create-geo-redundant-storage?tabs=dotnet11

Since the caveat with Geo-redundant storage is that it's read-only on the secondary until you make a request otherwise, I did find [GeoRedundantSecondaryUri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclientoptions.georedundantsecondaryuri?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_BlobClientOptions_GeoRedundantSecondaryUri) property  part of [BlobClientOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclientoptions?view=azure-dotnet) that will use the secondary address as part of a retry policy.